# Why some VariableDeclaration resolveBinding returns null but others does not

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am developing an eclipse plug-in to analyze the java source code. I traverse the whole AST tree and write a visitor to visit each variableDeclartionStatement, I noticed for some variables, the "resolvebinding" return an instance of IVariableBinding, but others does not. I can not differentiate them. BTW: I have set the ASTParser.setKind(K_COMPILATION_UNIT) and setResolveBindings(true). My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement vStatement) {
    Type theType = vStatement.getType();
    for(Iterator iterator = vStatement.fragments().iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
        VariableDeclarationFragment fragment = (VariableDeclarationFragment)iterator.next();
        IVariableBinding binding = fragment.resolveBinding();           
        if(binding !=null){
            ITypeBinding tBinding =  binding.getType();
            if(tBinding !=null){
                // if there is ArrayType, get the root type
                while(tBinding.getComponentType()!=null){
                    tBinding = tBinding.getComponentType();
                }
                System.out.println("USING BINDING VARIABLE CLASS IS: " + tBinding.getQualifiedName());  
            }

        }                       
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I differentiate the variable declarations which can resolve bindings with others which can not?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc on `VariableDeclarationFragment`:

> Variable declaration fragment AST node
>   type, used in field declarations,
>   local variable declarations, and
>   `ForStatement` initializers. It
>   contrast to
>   `SingleVariableDeclaration`, fragments
>   are missing the modifiers and the
>   type; these are located in the
>   fragment's parent node.

Try to get the type binding from the `VariableDeclarationFragment`'s parent.